# Dialog can't be blocked when FileChooser is open

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have question about blocking Dialog window when I'm opening FileChooser. When I open FileChooser from main app window I don't have any problem with blocking main window of app (using `fileChooser.showOpenDialog(Main.getPrimaryStage);`). But I have problem when I'm opening Filechooser from Dialog. I can't focus on main app window, because Dialog has property `dialog.initOwner(Main.getPrimaryStage());`, but I still can focus on Dialog and open next FileChooser, over and over again. [App image view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzJMX.png). What can I do with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a reference to the window used to display a dialog from its `dialogPane`, via:

```
Window dialogWindow = dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
```

Using this, you can make the "owner" of the file chooser the dialog's window:

```
Window dialogWindow = dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(dialogWindow);
```

Here's a SSCCE:

```
import java.io.File;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public class DialogFileChooser extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


        Button button = new Button("Open Dialog...");
        button.setOnAction(e -> createDialog(primaryStage).show());

        StackPane root = new StackPane(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Dialog<ButtonType> createDialog(Window owner) {

        DialogPane dialogPane = new DialogPane();
        dialogPane.getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CLOSE);

        Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();

        dialog.setDialogPane(dialogPane);

        Button openFile = new Button("Open File...");
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        openFile.setOnAction(e -> {
            Window dialogWindow = dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
            File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(dialogWindow);
            System.out.println(file);
        });
        dialogPane.setContent(new StackPane(openFile));

        dialog.initOwner(owner);
        return dialog ;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```